# ListView: instantly updating and time comparision

Tags: android-listview, google-cloud-messaging, android-service, android-adapter

I have to work on an application in which we are getting list of orders(with all details and **display_time**) and we have to show them in list view, but the condition is we have to show particular order on their exact **display_time**.

For example below are some orders with display time:

**order_id:** 101 |
**display_time (hh:mm:ss):** 09:10:00

**order_id:** 102 |
**display_time (hh:mm:ss):** 09:30:00

Then the requirement is:

- We have to show the orders on list on exact their display time.
- All order should come instantly as they entered in database.

**Edit**

The first thing that I need is:

- To get the order from database (SQL Server) instantly without hitting
  any API. Like push notification.

Then the second need is:

- To compare the device's time and order's display_time and if its matched then make visible the order in `ListView`. I have to do this for each order i think.

I don't know how can I do this.

So please suggest how can we do the above task.

Comment: Do you want to ascend the listview items based on time?

Comment: I want to show particular item on its display_time. Suppose I have two orders(101 and 102) to show on `listview`. Now I opened the orders screen at 09:10:00 then only order 101 should be visible.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand correctly. Mainly you want the list of items to be in the order of time from earliest to latest.

Here is one algorithm and it could be enhanced.

1. Allocate 100 (arbitrary) items/rows in the Listview.
2. If you only have 2 items or orders initially, make the other 98 rows not visible (state).
3. If a new order is entered, add the new order into one of the non-visible rows. And make it visible of course.
4. The issue in this case, you may have to reorder the items above the new order. However this is only a manipulation of text in your rows. A data structure is necessary to support this.

I claim this algorithm is fast. I think this is a good start.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for answer. I have edited my question, please see once more. and tell me what I have to use to achieve this.

Comment: @AshishTiwari, So...conceptually what is the problem with the approach I am suggesting?

Comment: How can I compare the time of order (in background) and update the list instantly is time matched to the device's time.

Comment: @AshishTiwari, There are solutions to this issue. One that I am thinking  of is that the server app or the SQL database provides the time of the order. Hence the date/time is stored in the database. When you get the data via pulling mechanism, you can simply compare device time with the one from the database.

Comment: How can we check in background. Suppose I get an order that is to be shown after 2 minutes. how can I check the order after 1 minute 59 seconds again.

Comment: @AshishTiwari, Your question is no longer directly related to the original problem. For a background process, you have to decide on 2 options I am thinking of. 1) Create a timer that executes every 2 minutes, and it will check for the time. This is easiest. 2) Create a callback interface between the server app and your device/phone app such that the server app notifies the phone app when a NEW order is requested. Does that make sense?